# Issue with IE not calling JQuery .load() function on page refresh - traced to image caching

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, image

This one has me scratching my head...

Working on a client site, they asked for a quick splash screen. This should cycle through a couple of images (the last one being their logo), then fade out and the main page fades in.

I found some code over at http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/ which works fine on FF, but is causing problems with IE7.

In IE7, the splash screen cycles until it gets to the last image, then stops - it does not fade out to the main page, it just sits there. If I click (which skips the splash and fades to the main page), it works, so the script isn't hung. After playing around, I found it was that particular file - logo-final.gif - which was causing the hang.

Long story shorter, it seems to be conflicting because I use logo-final.gif in the main page to show the logo. If I make a copy of logo-final.gif and call it logo-5.gif or whatever, it works. If I remove the img tag calling logo-final.gif from the main page, it works. But if I try and load logo-final.gif on the main page AND call it in the script, it doesn't work.

Is this just a weird IE7 bug? Any workarounds? I can get around it by copying the logo image and calling the new filename in the script, but what a waste of bandwidth (albeit tiny) just to coddle ol' craptastic IE7. Note - I've not tested in any other browsers than FF 3.6.15 and IE 7.0.5731.11 since I am on a loaner computer right now...

Thanks for any help!

Script and HTML below:

JQuery:

```
(function($){

$.fn.splashScreen = function(settings){

    settings = $.extend({

        imageLayers: [],
        imageShowTime: 700
    },settings);

    var splashScreen = $('<div>',{
        id: 'splashScreen',
        css:{
            height: $(document).height()+100
        }
    });

    $('body').append(splashScreen);
    splashScreen.click(function(){
        splashScreen.fadeOut('slow');
    });

    splashScreen.bind('changeImage',function(e,newID){

        if (settings.imageLayers[newID]){
            showImage(newID);
        } else {
            splashScreen.click();
        }
    });

    splashScreen.trigger('changeImage',0);

    function showImage(id) {
        var image = $('<img>',{src:settings.imageLayers[id]}).hide();

        image.load(function(){
            image.fadeIn('slow').delay(settings.imageShowTime).fadeOut('slow',function(){
image.remove();
                splashScreen.trigger('changeImage',[id+1]);
        });
    });

splashScreen.append(image);
}


return this;
}
})(jQuery);
```

HTML (in HEAD):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/splashScreen.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#logo').splashScreen({
     imageLayers : [
     'images/splash-1.gif',
     'images/splash-2.gif',
     'images/splash-3.gif',
     'images/logo-final.gif'
     ]
     });
});
</script>
```

And the img tag in the main page body which seems to be causing the conflict:

```
<h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-final.gif" alt="logo" /></a></h1>
```

Also, found the demo of the original tutorial also experiences the problem. To see it, go to http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/  -- the splashscreen should work fine the first time, but if you refresh (F5) in IE it should hang after the first image fades out.

Comment: I have no idea, my only thought was to add a query to one of the duplicates like `<img src="images/logo-final.gif?v=a" alt="logo" />` this would obviously waste extra bandwidth, at least once, so not really an answer for you.

Comment: At least I'm not going crazy, right?

Comment: Here's some more strangeness: I've renamed the file used by the script to "splash-4.gif" as a temp workaround. Loading the page from a new IE7 windows = success. HOWEVER, if I hit F5 to refresh, the page loads, it fades in the first image, fades it out, then STOPS. Same behavior, clicking triggers the click action so it's not hung, but it doesn't load the second image for some reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple solution would be to add a query to the "static" image at the html, like:

```
<img src="images/logo-final.gif?v=a" alt="logo" />
```

But this will use "extra" bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

OK - I got home and tested on IE8 and found the same issue. Debugging showed that image.load() was not being called when the image was cached - causing both my original problem (since img was loaded on main page) and my refresh issue. Solution was found at http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/

I changed the image declaration and .load function to the below, and all seems to be working!

```
var image = $("<img />")
   .attr("src",settings.imageLayers[id]+ "?" + new Date().getTime());
image.hide();

image.load(function(){
    image.fadeIn('slow').delay(settings.imageShowTime).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        image.remove();
        splashScreen.trigger('changeImage',[id+1]);  
    });
});
```

I hate IE! :)

Comment: but that's what I suggested on my first comment :) that will increase the bandwidth, I suggest you add the query just to the image on the html, unless the splash screen images all have problems after the first load?

Comment: jackJoe - yes, there were 2 separate issues. Your fix would've fixed the problem in the original post, but I had another issue when refreshing the page in IE with all of the images - it would cycle through the first one, sometimes the second, then choke. From what I have read, there's no real way to fix this without the increase in bandwidth - a big problem for people working on large CDN sites, but I suppose I can live with it. Changing the jquery to append the random query to every image call fixes both, and since this is only for the splash screen w/ small gif's, I'll take the bandwidth hit

Comment: @jackJoe - PS - I've already upvoted your comment with the answer, since you did technically post a correct solution for the posted question. If you want to add your comment as an answer to the question, I'll accept it as the proper answer!

Comment: @Jim, that's a pain, have you considered using a plugin like cycle-all, I've never had problems with images caching, it may be worth a try! P.S. I just posted my original answer thanks for the offer :)

Comment: @jackJoe - yea, just another reason IE<=8 needs to die! :) I haven't tried cycle-all, but I'll check it out. My research seems to indicate this happens most frequently when using smaller images...definitely a pain, hopefully this thread will save someone some pain!

Comment: The only problem of cycle-all for your case is the extra KB in an extra script (although for a straightforward fade the script is quite small, maybe you can study it?), but do try it and let me know if it solved your problem.