# image load event on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am developing a site, and I have to set the src of the not found images, to an error image.

the methods .load() and .error() works always except in IE.
I have been searching, and I have found this:

[Issue with IE not calling JQuery .load() function on page refresh - traced to image caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409974/issue-with-ie-not-calling-jquery-load-function-on-page-refresh-traced-to-im/5413989#5413989)

Adding the query string to the image, always loads it from server, and .load() and .error() methods works properly, however the site is quite too big, and I really can't load all images in site every time from server, without loading it from cache.

Any ideas of how make work this methods, without load from server every time the images for IE, or other way to check if image has been loaded correctly or not that work in IE?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the code you have tried?

Comment: The only way to get the load event to trigger on cached images consistently is to bind the load event before you set the src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very old bug that actually was fixed in all modern browsers except IE. 
They didn't trigger onload event if image was obtained from cache.

But there is a workaround that is well-known by every person who tried to create an image gallery in javascript a couple of years ago:)

Image DOM element has a property `.complete` that indicates whether image was loaded or not. You can check this property on script load. If image is in the cache img.complete will return true right after page loaded:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    //this code will not run in IE if image is in the cache
    $(this).on('load', function(){
       checkImage(this);
    });

    //this code will run if image is already in the cache
    if (this.complete) checkImage(this);
});

function checkImage(){
   //your code for checking image
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the fast answer, 

I have found this, and work fine, but some pages there are some ajax results, and the images are rendered after page load by javascript, and the complete is always in false in that case

Comment: Just tested in IE, in case you create images dynamically in javascript IE always fire onload event. Would you mind to show the sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server? A better method may be using .htaccess to rewrite all requests for images to a PHP script, and then if the image is not found, serve the image not found image

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, regrettably the server is windows running with IIS :/

There is no apache running on server

Comment: The same would be possible on IIS, though I would accept the answer left by @claustrofob