# Why is Angular event not firing in IE

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that is firing when images are loaded.

```
function imageLoaded() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('load', function () {
                // Emit if last in a repeater
                if (scope.$parent.$last) {
                    console.log('imagesLoaded');
                    scope.$emit('imagesLoaded');
                } else {
                    scope.$emit('imageLoaded');
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

And I have a directive that listen:

```
scope.$on('imagesLoaded', function () {
                    console.log('running isotope');
                    element.isotope({
                        itemSelector: '.puff-wrapper',
                        masonry: {
                            columnWidth: '.col-1'
                        }
                    });

                });
```

It works perfectly in FF and Chrome, but not in IE.

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: version: 2.1.3 @DonJuwe

Comment: @JimmyRare what version of IE? Have you tried appending your directive attribute with `data-`?

Comment: IE 11. Yes, i have tried data-.

Comment: possible duplicate of [image load event on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797786/image-load-event-on-ie)